# How can I do image wrapping in the div area of the table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do an exercise to write an image gallery w/o using any libraries or jquery. I put an image into a table cell. I have functions in javascript moveLeft() and moveright().

The bug that images moves out of the cell area. I want user will see only the part of the image when it passes cell border.

The css code:

```
#moving_image  {
    background-image: url(picture/13.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 130px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

The html code for cell:

```
.....
<tr height="130">
     <td width ="420" height="130">
         <div id= "moving_image">
         </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript code for moveRight() ,{as example. I also has moveLeft()}:

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    var x=10;
    function moveRight()
        var layerElement = document.getElementById("moving_image");
        x+=10;
        layerElement.style.left=x;
    }
 ....
</script>
```

So, what I do in order to wrap an image in the table cell? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using z-index for table row and the div containing your image
or give to table rows CSS parameter "overflow:hidden"

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping  with another div and apply that css to the wrapping div like:

```
<td>
   <div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden">
     <div id= "moving_image">
     </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the answer. Yes, it works. This is same as Sergei's one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply to make chaneg the `background-position` instead of moving the div.

```
function moveRight()
    var layerElement = document.getElementById("moving_image");
    x+=10;
    layerElement.style.background-position=x;
}
```